# Android app root permission with eng build BSP

Tags: java, android, root

Recently, I wrote an app and tried to access some linux devices.
But, It require root permission.
My machine was running eng build bsp, so the adb shell is rooted already(I guess..).
At least, I can use adb shell to access linux devices.

I used the following command to get the root permission, but it failed.

```
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());

        os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");

        os.flush();
```

Can anybody help on this?

Comment: The method you are using is applicable only to the "hack" sort of "su" deployed on "rooted" devices - it is not applicable to an engineering build with a default "su".  The proper solution where you control the build would be to create a set of linux group and matching android permission, and assign ownership of the device node to that group.

Comment: Really appreciate your reply~~